# How can I define a larger touch target in Windows Phone?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, windows-phone-8, touch, expression-blend

I'm working on  Windows Phone 8 app and I have a very small (25x5) `Image` which is bound to a `Tap` event. I'm afraid the user might have trouble pressing this small button and would like to increase the effective touch target, however nowhere in the API nor in Blend can I find this setting.

How to I make the touch target larger than the image itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try overlaying a Rectangle control over it, then making the Rectangle transparent in color. After that, all you have to do is to give it an action method.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking this would work but I figured there must be a better, more built-in way to do it. If there isn't, I'm happy to hack in some transparent rectangles.